# removing a case clause: bash expansion in sed regexp: X='a\.b' ; Y=';;' sed -n '/${X}/,/${Y}/d'

Tags: perl, bash, sed, variable-expansion

I'm trying to remove a case clause from a bash script. The clause will vary, but will always have backslashes as part of the case-match string.

I was trying sed but could use awk or a perl one-liner within the bash script.

The target of the edit is straightforward, resembles:

```
 $cat t.sh
 case N in 
 a\.b); 
   #[..etc., varies] 
 ;;
 esac
```

I am running afoul of the variable expansion escaping backslashes, semicolons or both. If I 'eval' I strip my backslash escapes.  If I don't, the semi-colons catch me up. So I tried subshell expansion within the sed. This fouls the interpreter as I've written it. More escaping the semi-colons doesn't seem to help.

```
X='a\.b' ; Y=';;'   
sed -i '/$(echo ${X} | sed -n 's/\\/\\\\/g')/,/$(echo ${Y} | sed -n s/\;/\\;/g')/d t.sh
```

And this:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless /${X}/ .. /{$Y}/' t.sh  # which empties t.sh
```

and

```
eval perl -i.bak -ne \'print unless /${X}/ .. /{$Y}/' t.sh  # which does nothing
```

Comment: your escape slashes look a bit backwards to me (should be ` \ ` not `/`). and inside a single quoted string, variables will not interpolate anyway, so a number of the escapes you have are redundant

Comment: erm. but this works (apologies for no pretty-print): 

   $ echo ${X} | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g'  ;  

   # a\\.b  ;
 
   $ sed -e '/a\\.b/,/\;\;/d' t.sh  ;

   $cat t.sh ;

   case N in   ;

   esac  ;


Which is the desired effect. The idea is to get a shell-friendly string into the sed programatically rather than interactively as above. That's where the apparently redundant escapes (which are \, the "/" are for sed delimiting) come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash's `printf` has a quoting feature that will help:

```
X='a\.b'; Y=';;'
sed "/$(printf "%q" "$X")/,/$(printf "%q" "$Y")/d" t.sh
```

or you can additionally use the `printf` variable assignment feature:

```
printf -v X "%q" 'a\.b'
printf -v Y "%q" ';;'
sed "/$X/,/$Y/d" t.sh
```

Note the use of double quotes around the `sed` command argument. Single quotes will prevent the expansion of variables and command substitution. When those aren't being used, though, it's usually best to use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
X='a\.b'
Y=';;'
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless /\Q'$X'/ .. /\Q'$Y'/' t.sh
```

This is playing games with shell quoting, but it works pretty well. :)

Comment: Gracias! I'm curious as to how to bend bash to my will, but I'll take this and run!

Comment: Changing my vote for solution. The Perl works, but the printf stays within bash.